# In android, is there any way to play an audio in just during call beeps before the call is picked up by other person?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, gsm, android-developer-api

In my android app, before a call is picked up, I want to just **replace the call beeps with an audio file?**
and once the call is picked up, I would turn off my audio file.

Please someone help me out in this issue!

**P.S:** The purpose of this feature is just to **replace the annoying call beeps** before the receiver on the other end picks up the call.

Comment: Please put your question in more clear way.

Comment: How far you are progressed??

Comment: @M.S.P please read out the question again, I've just edited it.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar we have just started to develop this feature

Comment: @TaimurSiddiqui as per my knowledge, it's little difficult to find out the time when the user picks the call where there is only state available is `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` which will get invoked when the call is being started.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar , that's pretty hopeless for me.... so there is no workaround even to play an audio file during call beeps without knowing about the CALL_STATE
Lets say, whenever any user dial the mobile number to start a call, my app would invoke and play the audio file through mobile phone speaker without worrying about when the receiver picks up the call because I guess once the receiver picks up the call, the audio file would automatically be turned off (according to android APIs)? 
What do you think?

Comment: @TaimurSiddiqui `once the receiver picks up the call` <- this state is very difficult to find, for the rest of the thing you can do it very easily.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar So could you please tell me how to do 'the rest of the thing' ? More specifically if you can tell me in terms of android code ? Because I can't figure it out that how to use mediaplayer or audio manager api in my code?

Comment: @TaimurSiddiqui Have you seen [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)?. It's clearly mentioned that > You cannot play sound files in the conversation audio during a call.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar yes I've seen this, that's why I'm finding some alternatives to do this, Thanks anyways for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

This person is playing an audio file during the call, please follow the link,
[My streaming audio player continues to play during a phone call - cannot make it stop! (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833522/my-streaming-audio-player-continues-to-play-during-a-phone-call-cannot-make-it)

Comment: I've already gone through this post, that's not what I want, anyways thanks for the answer